# How to run selenium webdriver code faster?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I made a bot that bought  items on amazon automatically if there is enough stock. But It doesn't work as fast as I want. How can I optimize the code for working faster. Any help will be appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import winsound
import time


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:")
prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)



driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\webdrivers\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
buyingStatus = True

while(buyingStatus):
    try:
        driver.get("URL")
        beGreedy = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('quantity'))
        beGreedy.select_by_value('1')
        addCart = driver.find_element_by_id("add-to-cart-button").submit()
        completeTheShopping = driver.find_element_by_id("hlb-ptc-btn-native").click()
    

        buyNow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html").click()


        freq = 500
        dur = 2000
        winsound.Beep(freq, dur)
        print("ITEM FOUND")
        buyingStatus = False

        

    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Item doesn't exist")
        driver.refresh()
```

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop? That may be not be running as you intend. I don't see any reason to use `while` if you are only checking one url. If you are iterating over multiple urls, use a for loop. Also, there is no way to really tell why the code is slow without having the link you are using because we cannot test your code.

Comment: Because it's always checking if there is stock. İf there is no stock, code is refreshing the page until load a stock.@TenaciousB

Comment: How is it not as fast as you want? I would think the loop would run as fast as the webpage loads, you might be getting rate limited too if it runs too quickly, but then it would probably raise an error. I would have this run as a single script and schedule it to run every few minutes using an external scheduler like cron or a windows alternative.

Comment: And Does it really matter which url I have ? Doesn't the bot run all urls at same time ? And actually What I mean is Is there anyway that I can optimize my code ? For example I don't download the images to make it faster. @TenaciousB

Comment: Well, nobody else can test it to see what's going on with the code if you don't put the actual url you are using in the code. Also, you only have about 5 functional lines in the loop that might be slowing it down but I'd think it was the response time from the server that would be your biggest bottleneck.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com.tr/yazdırma-RS1AWXY101J-baskı-20-ppm-elektronik/dp/B072MNK238/ref=zg_bs_14102471031_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=PP02SFBJ6ZTR7WSHKSE3 

This is the url @TenaciousB

Comment: I would suggest not hitting that .get() method as much.  (or the refresh) Use a webdriverwait there with like 30 second wait.  (This way you won't have to wait for page loads over and over... and I'd think Amazon would live update, though don't really know about that...)  Use findElements and check for empty array to see if it's there or not.  This way you won't need to catch/refresh.  If it's not found after 30 seconds it'll .get() again.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I pulled driver.get out and really helped. But I dont know either if Amazon have live update

Answer (score 0):

You could use webdriver waits to check if the button is there after a certain time 0.5 seconds(I'd suggest a higher number) at 0.1 seconds intervals(polling frequency). Also pull your driver.get() outside and just use the driver.refresh(). This also checks if you are capable of using your elements in the shortest amount of time you put down.

I am not sure if it updates automatically so I can't just use webdriver wait to just check if it's there without driver.refresh().

Also just use break from your method if there is no error.

Another idea would be to run it in headless to further improve it.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 0.5, poll_frequency=0.1)
driver.get("URL")

while True:
    try:
       
        beGreedy = Select(wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "quantity"))))
        beGreedy.select_by_value('1')        
        addCart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "add-to-cart-button"))).submit()
        completeTheShopping = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "hlb-ptc-btn-native"))).click()
        buyNow = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "html"))).click()

        freq = 500
        dur = 2000
        winsound.Beep(freq, dur)
        print("ITEM FOUND")
        break        

    except Exception:
        print("Item doesn't exist")
        driver.refresh()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: First of all, Really thanks for your answer. I added check and pull driver.get outside and ıt really made bot faster.(Abot 1.5 - 2 sec and ıts really a lot). But I tried to run it in headless but ıt gives error on "completeTheShopping" part (It automatically goes to Exception part and I don't konw why)